# MySQL Replication (3 masters, 1 Slave)

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

I am currently in the process of setting up mySQL replication.

I need to get data from three places.

So for example I have

**NEED THIS DATA**
server1 - database1
server2 - database2
server3 - database3

**STORE DATA HERE**
server4 - database4

I need this for reporting purposes.

I have read you can not connect to more then one master. So with that being said I am going to try a "master-chain" topology because I think I understand what is going on with this one

So the data flow will look like this

server1 -> **server2** -> **server3** -> server4

**server2** and **server3** will have blackhole storage engines for the replicated databases so we don't actually store the information on these servers but the information is still logged to the binary-log so all the statements will trickle down to keep server4 up to date.

Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: I believe as of 5.1 or 5.2, MySQL DOES support multiple-master setups. EDIT: Apparently that feature never made it... But this may help http://mysqlmusings.blogspot.com/2011/04/round-robin-multi-source-in-pure-sql.html

Comment: @josh.trow, that should really be an answer!

Comment: @josh.trow - Thanks that article is very informative.  So basically the slave is just switching between masters in a timely fashion.  So all the work is being done on the slave and the 3 masters will just be producing the binary logs?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I know that system wouldn't work for the company I work for since we have too much data flowing in replication to stop reading from any log for 20 minutes, but for most setups it should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work but isn't the nicest implementation and might well cause you problems in the future. Before you add a new table on server1 or server2 you'll have to create the `BLACKHOLE` tables on the downstream servers otherwise you'll end up with the real tables. I guess you could work around this by writing a script that runs on server2 and server3 each night that looks for any non-blackhole tables and runs an `ALTER TABLE` to modify them into `BLACKHOLE` tables.

Do you need the reporting data to be bang up to date? If not I'd recommend throwing out this whole idea and just pulling dumps of the data into server4 periodically as required.

**edit: (the next day)** After some thought I think that if this was me I would probably look at running three separate MySQL instances on **server4** each of them as a direct slave of one of the servers.

Using this approach there's no replication *chain*, the replication setup is far simpler/normal and each db pair is self contained.

It's easy and fairly normal to run multiple MySQL instances, there's even a tool called [mysqld_multi](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-multi.html) that will help you to set it up.

Comment: Hi I appreciate your answer.  Yes these reports need to be up to date becuase they will be used for internal purposes.  Right now we are using navicat to sync these databases and it runs 4 times a day (which isn't cutting it).  We are also running into problems with navicat and my boss would like to move away from it.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Also what kind of problems could occur from doing this?  Thanks again

Comment: You are just pushing a lot of extra data through the line of servers, it would work though.

Comment: Bobby - I've got to ask why there are three master servers and if you really need three. Do they run different applications? Does one application use more than one of the servers?

Comment: @James C - 2 servers are shopping carts (hosted off site) and the third keeps internal information locally.  So we are trying to bring all this information to one place to run internal reports for our staff.  We have a site set up on server 4 to allow them to run reports and applications at the moment but some of the report are useless if they are not up to date.

Comment: Thanks James C I just read what you wrote I think I will give that a try instead of the master chain.  I knew the chain wasn't the best option but I understood it the most (I thought) and figured I post for some feedback before I tried anything.  Ill post back and let you know how it goes.  Thanks again

Comment: @James C - I set up multiple mySQL instances and it works like a charm.  Thanks for the help. now I just have to find a way to monitor the slaves to make sure data is consistent with product server and slaves are running

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! Write a script to check the output of `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` and then if you need to do consistency checks use: `mk-table-checksum` http://www.maatkit.org/doc/

Comment: @James C if I write it in PHP how would I get it to run every few minutes to check connection?  Would cron do the trick?

Comment: yup - cron would work fine. Email on failure. You probably want to check lag and that both threads are running. Watch out checking for NULL and 0 on the lag!

Comment: @James C Thanks again! I wrote a script and it works the way I want it.  Just have to implement the mk-table-checksum for consistency checks and I think I will be all set!  Do you think I should do anything else so if a slave does go down it will make it an easy fix?